# How do I keep stdin open when launching an executable via a Desktop Entry File (i.e. .desktop)?

Tags: desktop-environment, stdin, xdg, freedesktop, desktop-file

I have a desktop application that relies on stdin.

If I run it in the terminal, it runs great and quits when stdin closes (CTRL+D).  I also have a systemd activation socket set up which can launch this application.  In this case, stdin is connected to the socket and when that socket is closed, the application closes.

But when I launch this via `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` in gnome, stdin is closed and so the application closes immediately.  I see stdin is linked to `/proc/12345/fd/0 -> /dev/null`.

Is there a way to launch an application via the desktop environment so that stdin is open (even if it doesn't have anything writing to it)?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question, but couldn't applying a suitable redirection in your .desktop file be a viable option? E.g. `Exec=/path/to/program </some/file`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that `bash` redirection was supported in `Exec=`. This would probably work!  I just need to find a file that's always open now.

Comment: (Sorry, deleted a wrong comment of mine) -- I don't know how supported it is. It seems to work in KDE (I can't test it using GNOME), but it is not mentioned in the Desktop Entry Specification and no .desktop file on my system makes use of it.

Comment: You can run it in a terminal by setting `Terminal=true`

Comment: @fra-san Even if it isn't supported, one can always write a wrapper script for the application (which will be used by the `.desktop` file) and redirect stdin inside that script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the latest version of the [FreeDesktop Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) is under-specified in regards to how implementations should set up standard IO. The [list of defined keys](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) mention nothing about this and neither does the [section on the exec key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html). Therefore, it would probably be unwise to rely on undocumented, implementation-specific behavior to achieve this task (e.g. assuming the implementations you care about execute EXEC in a shell or otherwise use `system(3)`).

As for a solution, I would second the recommendations given in the comments: Either wrap your command with a program that keeps stdin out, or launch it in a terminal window:

- ```
  Terminal=true
  ```
- ```
  Exec=sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null | YOUR_APP'
  ```